# How do you link to a page in Hexo.js?

Tags: hexo

I know you can link to a post like `{% post_link 2018-10-19-hexo-3-8-released 'Link to a post' %}`, but how do you link to a page located somewhere like `/assets/apps/app1/index.html`?

I don't want to hardcode it in HTML because I deploy my site to two different domains.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the relative path to link the static page, but you must put the assets folder to source folder firstly, then you need to use command `hexo g` to copy the folder to public folder, Now you can found that the static HTML page is generated to path `public/source/assets/apps/app1/index.html`. And you use a relative path to link it.

It seems like link a assets img.

Answer (score 0):

For assets there are [asset_path and asset_link](https://hexo.io/docs/tag-plugins#Include-Assets) but for pages there is nothing yet (see issue [#4749](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/4749)).

```js
{% asset_link public/source/assets/apps/app1/index.html 'Title here' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

[My solution in Github](https://github.com/DuGuYifei/Hexo_File_link).

Here I change the renderer.js to let my hexo can auto change  into  then it can open the link. Because hexo will make a folder in same name of file and have a index.html inside. But it's only used for whose permalink is ":title". But you can change the link function inside by ur self to fill your own needs.